# module load command doesn't work following environment module installation

Tags: drivers, bash

I recently installed environment-modules onto my ubuntu workstation. When I first encountered the error "module load command not found", I attempted to follow the instructions given in the response to this post:

["module load" command does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343692/module-load-command-does-not-work)

I ran add.modules, and then I went in to edit the .bashrc startup script as instructed in the post. One key difference I found was that the commented out line was not added to the bash startup script, i.e.

```
case "$0" in
-sh|sh|*/sh)  modules_shell=sh ;;
   -ksh|ksh|*/ksh)  modules_shell=ksh ;;
   -zsh|zsh|*/zsh)  modules_shell=zsh ;;
-bash|bash|*/bash)  modules_shell=bash ;;
esac
module() { eval `/usr/Modules/$MODULE_VERSION/bin/modulecmd $modules_shell $*`; }
#module() { eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd $modules_shell $*`; }
```

So I added it manually, commenting out the line above and de-commenting the last line.

However, now when I try to run

```
module load <myprogram>
```

I just get the error "No module path defined"

Is there something that I'm missing? Most likely it was the step of creating a directory modulefiles. Where does this directory go (should it be in /usr/Modules?), and what do I need to put there in order to be able to execute module load? I'm afraid I have no experience setting up module files, so it's not clear where they should be located nor how to configure the file content.